# Add columns to a rolling-apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `daily_data` data like this:

```
                 Close
Date
2022-06-01  148.710007
2022-05-31  148.839996
2022-05-27  149.639999
2022-05-26  143.779999
2022-05-25  140.520004
2022-05-24  140.360001
2022-05-23  143.110001
2022-05-20  137.589996
2022-05-19  137.350006
2022-05-18  140.820007
...
```

I then do a rolling percent change calculation, `sampleStr` = '180 D':

```
dfSeries = daily_data['Close'].rolling(resampleStr).apply(lambda x : (x[0] - x[-1])/x[0])
```

If I print this I get this:

```
Date
2022-06-01    0.000000
2022-05-31   -0.000874
2022-05-27   -0.006254
2022-05-26    0.033152
2022-05-25    0.055074
2022-05-24    0.056150
2022-05-23    0.037657
2022-05-20    0.074776
2022-05-19    0.076390
2022-05-18    0.053056
2022-05-17   -0.003564
2022-05-16    0.021317
2022-05-13    0.010759
2022-05-12    0.041356
2022-05-11    0.014861
2022-05-10   -0.039002
```

However, I would like to add `columns` to this for a sanity check, I would like to add the Date of `x[0]` (actually this is already there I think), the Date of `x[-1]`, the Close of `x[0]`, and the Close of `x[-1]`, to `dfSeries`.

How do I do this?

Comment: For a bit of clarity, are you able to give a desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to use `pd.concat` with `shift`ed columns

For example, if your window is `3`, you can do

```
pd.concat([df['Close'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x : (x[0] - x[-1])/x[0]).reset_index(), 
           df.reset_index()['Date'].shift(-3).rename('Date in T-3'), 
           df.reset_index()['Close'].shift(-3).rename('Close in T-3')], 
           axis=1
           )
```

which means you are concatenating three objects. The first one, is the result you provided in the original post; the second one, the shifted `Date` column; and the last one, the shifted `Close` column.

Comment: rafaelc that is very close but I only see one Close? I need two closes and two dates.

Comment: the close of `x[0]` is just `df.reset_index()['Close']`. You should have two dates at the end.

Comment: Huh? Why would I need to reset the index? I don't need once close, I need many closes, one for each x[0]. I need the close of the given row? I do have two dates, I just don't have the close of x[0] for the given row

Comment: Sorry, that does appear to be correct